# How to save generated pdf in server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

Currently I am generating a pdf using prawn gem of rails. pdf is generated when user hit on this action

```
def print_pdf
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @details = @user.details_data
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        pdf = PrintDetailsPdf.new(@user, view_context, @details)

          send_data pdf.render, filename: "#{@user.id}.pdf",
                  type: 'application/pdf',
                  disposition: 'inline'
      end
    end
  end
```

In above action, I generate the pdf and show it in browser and it works perfectly. But I want to show the pdf in browser and also save the pdf at server in public/user_details directory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some good gems that help in file uploading and saving. [Here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads) is a list of these gems. Paperclip and Carrierwave are the most popular options.

You could also implement it from scratch. Rails has built-in helpers which make it easy to roll your own solution.

```
pdf_content = *Content you want to save in the file*
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'user_details', filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(pdf_content.read)
end
```

It depends on the complexity of what you want to achieve, but this is totally sufficient for easy file saving tasks. Go [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) to find more information.

Comment: from my above code pdf is the created pdf object. so in your code what should I put for pdf_content

Comment: should I put pdf_content = pdf

Comment: You could try creating a separate def and instead of sending data (using `send_data`), you could try `return pdf` or maybe `return pdf.render` and use it as pdf content. I am not aware of how your `print_pdf` works, so can only say this much.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
pdf_string = render_to_string :template => 'template', :layout => false 
     File.open("public/userfiles/example.pdf", 'wb') { | 
f| f.write(pdf_string) } 
  end
```

Render the template to string and then create a file and write that pdf to it..
This should help